# Selenium grid 2 chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I’m using Selenium 2.42.2 on Windows 7. I started a hub and typed:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=
D:\selenium\chromedriver.exe
```

in my terminal. The following is a JUnit 4 test case that gets executed:

```java
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8443/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testWebdriver() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/customizedfolder/main.html");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='f21TemFolder']/div/span"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='f21TemFolder']/div/span")).click();
}
```

The content of the `nodeconfig.json` file is:

```json
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "*firefox",
            "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium",
            "platform": "LINUX",
            "maxInstances": 3
        },
        {
            "browserName": "*chrome",
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
            "platform": "LINUX",
            "maxInstances": 3
        }
    ],
    "configuration": {
        "nodeTimeout": 120,
        "port": 5555,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "hubHost": "localhost",
        "nodePolling": 2000,
        "registerCycle": 10000,
        "register": true,
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "maxSession": 1
    }
}
```

However, it cannot open chrome, the error is:

> the path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property....

I also set `webdriver.chrome.driver` in the system properties, but that didn’t help.

- Chrome version: 36.0.1985.143 m
- Chrome driver version: 2.10

How to use Chrome in Selenium grid 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i think the problem in `-Dwebdriver` arg, you should write `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver`
smth like this...

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\selenium\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: sorry, it's typo, i input the -Dwebdriver as you said, but failed.

Comment: Well, really strange then. Because next line works on my side (i use it to start my node) java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Tools\SelenuimDrivers\Chrome\chromedriver.exe" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=latest,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver". Could you provide more info? is this test fails? or you failing to start node?

Comment: Node was started successful, just test failed.  At the beginning, I wanted to use chrome in Ubuntu 12.04(hub and node were in Ubuntu), failed with same error, then I tried to use chrome in Windows 7, failed too(the node was in Windows 7, the hub was in Ubuntu.)

Comment: Not sure (some thoughts =) ), but seems the problem here `driver = new ChromeDriver();` possibly: 1. path to chromedriver.exe has not been added to %path% in windows7 2. Or, run tests using RemoveWebDriver instead of `var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("path to site"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());`. Let's try this way, and see whats happen =)

Comment: You are right! After I changed to `driver = new RemoteWebDriver()` and changed browser name from *chrome to chrome in json config file, then it can open chrome browser. Thanks. `driver = new ChromeDriver()' is from selenium IDE.

Comment: @AndreyEgorov thanks for the reply it solved my problem! Is there any wat to add -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver in the node config.json file instead?